# Storing user-created logic in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database-design

I have a node app (express.js) and I want to create a web interface where the user will be able to implement some logic about when an event is to be triggered. All of this has to be stored on the database (MongoDB). (other ideas are welcome too)

I want the user to implement complete if/while statements.
As if you have one column with variables (mongo fields of various documents of a specific model) and you can test any of them however you want (ex. add them, sub them, compare them with a value or another variable).
Also, you have another column with events (actually js functions) that will be triggered when the if/while statement is true such as send an email with the value of a variable or send a tweet with a warning message.

I know that saving a function in a document is NOT a good idea. Mongo is designed to store documents, not code. Is that true?

How can I design that?

Code is not what I'm looking for but it's always welcome. Also sorry, but I'm not a book guy, I don't want book/pdf recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best option is to store javascript code that the user enters (either via text editor or create via dragging blocks) in a document and execute it in a separate [node sandbox](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html).

I'm kinda concerned about the security of the vm, but node is used in production environments so it might be just my idea...